# How Can I Set Miniumum Hour for Date in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the date and time of the first day of the prior month; specifically as it is January I'm trying to get: `Sun Dec 01 00:00:00 EST 2013`. I am using the below code snippet which I have modified from another found here on Stackoverflow while researching this subject; this code snippet will return: `Sun Dec 01 12:00:00 EST 2013`. I do not understand why setting the minimum hour for the 1st in fact returns noon.

```
Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// add -1 month to current month
aCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
// set DATE to 1, so first date of previous month
//aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);                        
aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, aCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
aCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, aCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR));
aCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, aCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
aCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, aCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
Date firstDateOfPreviousMonth = aCalendar.getTime();
```

If I modify the following line as shown and set 0 I get the same result:

```
aCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
```

If I modify it as follows I get 1pm:

```
aCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
```

Result: `Sun Dec 01 13:00:00 EST 2013`

Comment: From what I learned, Joda-time is a hell of a lot easier to use than `Calendar` http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: @EmbattledSwag From what I've learnt, JodaTime is much more powerful and to someone unfamiliar to the API, confusing - that is not an excuse not to use it though, I just wouldn't say it was "easier" - IMHO ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Docs

> HOUR Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning
>   or afternoon.

You'll want to use `HOUR_OF_DAY` instead

> HOUR_OF_DAY Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the
>   day.

Or set the `AM_PM` accordingly...

> AM_PM Field number for get and set indicating whether the HOUR is
>   before or after noon.

In any case, take the time to consult the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: The following change worked:
    aCalendar.set( Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM );
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, aCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

Comment: That makes a nice change :P

Answer (score 0):

Some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

Using default time zone, we create a `DateTime` instance of now (current moment), go back to previous month (in a smart manner, compensating for short month like February), get the first of month by asking for "minimum value", and then get first moment of that first-of-month day.

```
org.joda.time.DateTime startOfPreviousMonth = new org.joda.time.DateTime().minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Note the method `withTimeAtStartOfDay` to get the first moment of the day. That moment may or may not be 00:00:00 in local time (because of Daylight Saving Time or other anomalies).

Using explicit time zone (almost always a better practice)…

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forId( "Europe/Paris" ); // "Asia/Kolkata" etc.
org.joda.time.DateTime startOfPreviousMonth = new org.joda.time.DateTime( timeZone ).minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Get a string…

```
String string = startOfPreviousMonth; // or startOfPreviousMonth.toString();
```

To convert back to a java.util.Date instance for communicating with other libraries…

```
java.util.Date date = startOfPreviousMonth.toDate();
```